# return function main menu in c

Tags: c, menu, return, program-entry-point

I'm starting coding this week so I'm dummy about it. I need help about return to main in my script. For example when I done Course registration part I can't return menu program is crashing

Codes:

```
#include <stdafx.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void eng();
void menu();
void huh();

int main()
{
    menu();

    return 0;
}

void menu()
{
    int menu1choice;

    printf("Menu\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf("1. Student Registration\n");
    printf("2. Show Students.\n");
    printf("Please enter number: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &menu1choice);
    switch (menu1choice)
    {
        case 1:
        {
            eng();
            break;
        }

    }
}

void eng()
{
    int a = 5;
    char name[30];

    printf("1.Student Number: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &a);
    //student number
    printf("2.Name: ");
    scanf_s("%s", &name);
    //student name
    getchar();
}

void huh()
{
    int a = 5;
    char name[30];

    printf("Your Student number: %d\n", a);
    printf("Your Name: %s\n", name);
    //result
    getchar();
}
```

Pls help me write return code lines, Thanks in Advance

Comment: You invoked *undefined behavior* for using indeterminate value of uninitialized variable having automatic storage duration in `printf("Your Name: %s\n", name);`

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow, This is just a message I send to new members to help things along a bit. The learning curve for a new user isn't steep as such, but finding out how to use stack isn't always obvious. Please do take a few minutes and have a look here [ask] and it's also important to look here .. [mcve].. Also, if an answer is valid for you, click on the tick to the left of the answer so that the question is marked as answered and this makes sure that the person who posted it gets reputation. Cheers.

Comment: `scanf_s("%s", &name);` --> `scanf_s("%29s", name, 30);` (30 <=> sizeof(name) )

Comment: Hmmm... Actually `huh()` isn't called, so it won't invoke *undefined behavior*.

Comment: ah okay thanks it fixed the crash,but what about get to main menu again?

Comment: huh() is working normal

Comment: use loop. E.g `while(1){ menu(); }` and add exit menu.

Comment: You don't need the `{}` in the `case` but you should really put a `default` clause  to handle all other situations. Also post the code for scanf_s

Comment: @terencehill He doesn't have scanf_s()'s source code, it's part of Microsoft's C Run-Time Library. The main difference with the standard C scanf() is that it requires a buffer size whenever "%s" is used.

Comment: Non-prototype function declarators are deprecated: `void eng()` -> `void eng(void)`, `int main(void)`, etc.

Comment: Read the man page/documentation of functions you use! You unvoke undefined behaviour: `scanf_s("%s", &name);` -> `scanf_s("%s", &name, (rsize_t)sizeof(name));`

Comment: @Medinoc: `scanf_s` is not MS-specific, but standard C.

Comment: @terencehill: There is no need for a `default`. If no label matches, nothing is executed in the `switch` body.

Comment: @Olaf, I didn't say it's needed, I just think that it's a good practice, however my sentence could be misinterpreted, so thanks to have pointed it out.

Comment: There's just too many fundamental errors to decipher a specific question or even a specific bug. The only thing anyone can say about this, is that you have to study the very basics of C programming. SO is not an interactive beginner tutorial and not a replacement for traditional studies. Rather, it is a site for programmers.

Comment: @Olaf: Wow, I had no idea this had actually been accepted into C11. Especially funny as Microsoft routinely defecates on any C standard past C90...

Comment: @Medinoc: It is somewhat redundant, as you can use the field-width for that. It might be intended for variable length character codes like UTF-8 to store the most characters and not have to be prepared for the worst-case. Not sure if that is a good idea, though.

Comment: @terencehill: In old K&R C, not having a matching label (including `default`) was not specified -> UB. Compilers were free (and some did) to generate the best "sunshine code" (i.e. code which fails with unexpected input).

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that may help you understand how to the mechanics of functions returning values, in your case back to the main function.

As for some advice, please read up about magic numbers and specifically why they are bad.

```
/*
 *  35917794_main.c
 */

#include <stdio.h>

#define     STU_REG         1
#define     STU_SHOW        2
#define     EXIT_SUCCESS    0

unsigned int show_menu(void);

unsigned int main
        (
        unsigned int    argc,
        unsigned char   *arg[]
        )
{
    unsigned int    menu1choice;
/*
 *  The next statements says run the function show_menu() and put the returned
 *  result in the variable menu1choice.
 */
    menu1choice = show_menu();
    switch(menu1choice)
        {
        case (STU_REG):
            {
            printf("\nGo do STUDENT REGISTRATION things...\n\n");
            break;
            }
        case STU_SHOW:
            {
            printf("\nGo do SHOW STUDENT things...\n\n");
            break;
            }
        default:
            {
            printf("\nGo do something for invalid option...\n\n");
            break;
            }
        }
    return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}


unsigned int show_menu
        (
        void
        )
{
    unsigned int    ui_W0;
    printf("Menu\n\n");
    printf("1. Student Registration\n");
    printf("2. Show Students.\n");
    printf("Please enter number: ");
    scanf("%d", &ui_W0);
/*
 *  The next statements says run the function show_menu() has finished and returned
 *  returns the result in the variable ui_W0.
 */
    return(ui_W0);
}
```